Stripping prefix in python module name
I have the following tree structure:
volleybot/
- vbt/
+- BUILD
+- api.py
- tests/
+- BUILD
+- api_test.py

From tests/api_test.py, I would like to be able to write: from vbt import api, instead of from volleybot.vbt import api. How can I do that?

You could possibly use the PYTHONPATH environment variable. More specifically with Bazel, you could declare one a dependency of the other.

You're missing vbt/__init__.py here, required for any import to work. Are you just leaving them out as obvious noise? (I'm guessing so because you're sugging from volleybot.vbt import api works, but it would be better to list them if so.)

TL;DR
The syntax you are looking for is from ..vbt import api, but it has some limitations.
Details
You can do relative imports with the .. syntax to import from a sibling module without naming the parent:
tests/api_test.py:
from ..vbt import api
# test stuff

and then run it with
python -m unittest volleybot.tests.api_test

or the equivalent in the unit testing framework of your choice.
Limitations
Unfortunately, this only works if Python recognizes that api_test was loaded as volleybot.tests.api_test.
While the command above will work, none of these will:
python volleybot/tests/api_test.py  # even if it has a guarded main block
cd volleybot/tests; python -m unittest api_test.py

or any other way to invoke api_test.py where you are not effectively running import volleybot.tests.api_test explicitly or implicitly as the mechanism to load it.
In these cases, you will get this error message:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

because Python does not know what the parentage of api_test is, and therefore it cannot determine that vbt is in a sibling module.
In my projects, I avoid such relative imports, at least for unit testing code, because I want to have full flexibility in how I invoke each part of my unit test suites, but if that's not a requirement for you, relative imports from ..vbt may be your answer.
Assumptions
I'm assuming you already have a (possibly empty) __init__.py in each directory, otherwise no imports are going to work anyway.
I'm also assuming you've done a pip install -e . or similar so your module is importable.
If these assumptions are wrong, you need to turn your code into an installable module before we can start talking about relative imports.
